# Function with property $\lambda f(x,y,z) = f(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z)$?

Tags: calculus, functions

What is the name of a function that has the property $\lambda f(x,y,z) = f(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z)$? These types of functions are primarily seen in thermodynamics and I wanted to learn more about them and their properties.

Comment: It is known as a homogenous multivariate function of degree one.

Comment: [Homogeneous function of degree one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function)

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, $f(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z) = \lambda^d f(x,y,z)$ are the homogeneous multivariate functions of degree $d$.